# How to use xamarin sidebar with storyboard

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, sidebar

I'm trying to create a application with sidebar drawer navigation, but the controls is hard coded in your controller like what I see in the example, What I want is my sidebar menu and content will be designed in storyboard, the problem is I really don't know where to start.

rootviewcontroller.cs

```
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using SidebarNavigation;
namespace Casebook.IOS
{
public partial class RootViewController : UIViewController
{
    public SidebarController sideBar { get; private set; }

    public RootViewController() : base(null,null){

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        sideBar = new SidebarController (this,new  ContentViewController(), new SideMenuController());
        sideBar.MenuLocation = SidebarController.MenuLocations.Left;
    }
}
```

sidemenucontroller.cs

```
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Casebook.IOS
{
    public partial class SideMenuController : BaseController
    {
    public SideMenuController () : base(null,null)
    {
    }
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
    }
}
```

contentviewcontroller.cs

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Casebook.IOS
{

public partial class ContentViewController : BaseController
{
    public ContentViewController():base(null,null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

    }
}
```

so basically there's nothing in my codes since my ui's is initialize from my storyboard.

attach is how i setup my storyboard, each of this view is already set by their respective controller classes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vttcf.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for drawer/sidebar/slider/flyout/*[your alias here]* menus in the iOS designer.

You can design the contents of the view controllers you want to use in the designer, then load them from the storyboard and set them in your sidebar controller.

In your Storyboard, give the menu controller and the content controller a storyboard ID and then create instances of them in your code using `UIStoryboard.InstantiateViewController(string)` (you'll need to cast the result to the actual `UIViewController` subclasses).

Presuming you're in `ViewDidLoad()` of some view controller:

```
var content = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("ContentControllerId") as ContentViewController;
var menu = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("MenuControllerId") as SideMenuController;

sideBar = new SidebarController (this, content, menu);
```

Comment: geez, thanks this works, i never thought that you can actually load your your uiview in your storyboard. Thanks a lot!